need to extract files from a different folder using filter activity
I have 10 folders from that i have given filter activity condition to extract a folder name 'Series'. Inside that folder again i have different folders and again i have given filter activity condition to extract a folder name 'Schedule'. again inside that folder i have 5 different folders and inside those 5 different folders, i have multiple files and from those files i need to extract only files which are ending with '20231026.txt'
I have tried giving Filter activity condition as @endswith(item().name,'20231026.txt') to extract 20231026.txt files from different folders. But till folders it is extracting but inside 5 different folders, I have files ending with 20231026.txt which is not getting filtered out after providing conditions.

Instead of using filter activities to filter folders and files, use data flow transformations to get multiple files from subdirectories and inside subdirectories. Follow the procedure below:
Create a delimited dataset with the file path up to the container only and uncheck the First row as header.

Create a dataflow with the above dataset as the source. In the source settings, provide the wildcard file path like this Series/Schedule/*/* and add a column for the file name.

This will merge all the file rows and add a column containing that row's file path.

Next, take an aggregate transformation and group by the filepath column. In the aggregate section, create a sample column count with the expression count(filepath).

This will create a column with all the required file paths.

Take a select transformation and delete the extra column count. Add a filter transformation to it and use the endsWith(filepath, '20231026.txt') expression to extract the files ending with '20231026.txt'.

You will get all the files ending with '20231026.txt' from the required path as shown below:

